# Script Task Error : Insufficent System Storage. The server response was : 4.5.3. Too many recipients (AS780090)

Tags: c#, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, script-task

I have created a simple SSIS package with SMTP task/C# to send an automated email to a couple of recipients.

When I run it manually from Visual Studio 2017, it is working fine for one recipient or a couple of recipients, but when I deployed and run the SSIS Package on Azure (Lift and Shift SSIS Package on ADF V2), it is not working for a couple of recipients, but it is working for one recipient.

When I have only one recipient, it is sending an email without any issue on Azure, but when I gave a couple of email ids either both the email ids in 'To' or one in 'To' the other email id in 'Cc', it is not working.
Note - The Same SSIS Package is working fine on Visual Studio 2017 when I run it manually, so there is no issue with the package, code or design.

I created an SSIS Package with just one Send Mail Task in SSIS with a couple of email ids, one in 'To' and the other email id in 'Cc'. Same thing I tried using C# script in SSIS as well and getting the same error

Error Message

> Script Task Error: Insufficient System Storage. The server response was: 4.5.3. Too many recipients (AS780090) [AM5EUR02FTxxx.eop.EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com]

Feel free to ask any questions if this is not clear.

*C# Script*

```cs
public void Main()
{
    //try
    //{
        // TODO: Add your code here
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromadress@domain.co.uk", "toaddress@domain.co.uk");
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("cc@domain.co.uk"));
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Host = "domain-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com";
        mail.Subject = "Test Email";
        mail.Body = "test email.";
        //client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mail);

    //}
    //catch
    //{ }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: Some example data and code would help.

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We moved to a new production server to support .net core services while still running our main API in .net framework, which is where we're getting this error. Our staging server does not have this issue, only production, and we can't figure out why. It always sends with one recipient, it always errors out for multiple. However, the first person on the list does get the email, and it shows everyone it was sent to.

Comment: @Mathachew You're emailing from the MX server.  MX only sends one email to one recipient.

Comment: @EllieK It turned out to be a propagation issue after the SPF record was updated. After about three days emails started going through without issue. I'll need to make they update SPF records several days, if not a week, before we deploy a new server.